# Probability that the average of a binary sequence deviates from $\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-probability

Is there a known estimate in terms of $n\in\mathbb{N},\varepsilon>0$ of the probability that a random sequence $x_1,\dots,x_n$ with $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ satisfies that for any $k$ with $2k<n$ we have $\left|\frac{x_1+\dots+x_{2k}}{2k}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\varepsilon$?

I am interested in upper bounds for the mentioned probability, substantially better than the one given by just $\left|\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\varepsilon$ (when $n$ is even). I am also just interested in the case where $n$ is big and $\varepsilon$ is small.

Comment: I don't want a closed formula or anything, just an estimate for big $n$ and small $\varepsilon$. By the way from your comment may you have read $x_i\in[0,1]$ instead of $x_i\in \{0,1\}$? If not I don't understand it very well

Comment: I deleted my comment.  You are right; I misinterpreted the problem.

Comment: This is still a very tricky problem.  Superficially, one might surmise that each pair of values $x_{2k+1}, x_{2k}$ must be distinct values in $\{0,1\}$.  However, that isn't so.  For fixed $\epsilon$, there has to be a value of $N$ such that for $k > N$, ordered pairs such as $(x_{2k+1}, x_{2k}) = (0,0)~$ or $~(1,1)$ will *start to be temporarily tolerated*.

Comment: Yes, it isn't obvious to me at all. That's why I asked it here, maybe this is related to some probability distribution or something known by statisticians

Comment: Re my previous comment, furthermore, there will be situations in which $(x_{2k+1}, x_{2k})$ may (for example) equal $(0,0)$ but may not equal $(1,1).$  This is why I advise computer simulations.  For fixed $N$ and $\epsilon$, I would run the simulation $1000$ times, and see what happens.  Your computer will need a reliable way of *randomly* selecting from $\{0,1\}.$

Comment: A *semi-alternative* is to select a fixed value for $N$, and then run $100,000$ simulations.  Then, you could have the computer determine, the probability of a satisfying sequence, as a function of $\epsilon$.  This type of approach may lead to **accidental analytical insights**.

Comment: I can do that, but the thing is, I do not know almost anything about probability, I just thought this could be useful while thinking about [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420897/what-is-the-smallest-size-of-a-shape-in-which-all-fixed-n-polyominos-can-fit). I prefer to see first if this is an easy consequence of some probability result I don't know, if not I may run some simulations as you say or try other way of attacking the problem

Answer (score 1):

Consider the terms (I use capital letters for random variables) $Y_n=(-1)^{X_n}$ which converts the terms of the sum to $\pm 1$ instead of $0,1.$
Note that if there are exactly $f$ 1's in your sum of $X_n$ this is equivalent to the $\pm 1$ sum of $Y_n$'s being $(n-f)-f=n-2f$ so we might as well consider the question below:

Let $S_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$ then one can show [Spitzer, *Principles of Random Walk*, 2nd Edition, p.45] that there is a constant $a>0$ so that:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon\right)\leq 2 e^{-a\epsilon^2 n}
$$
for all $n\geq 1.$ If the $Y_n$ are not uniform (say $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=+1)=p$) this will stil hold with a different constant $a=a(p)$ if one looks instead at the deviation not from zero but from $2p-1.$

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, although not exactly an answer to my question. But maybe using this and inclusion-exclusion gives a lower bound for the probability. The problem is that for small $n$, $2e^{-a\varepsilon^2n}$ is $>1$, which is a small problem for the inclusion-exclusion argument. But what I was interested in is proving that for fixed $\varepsilon$ the probability of my question is $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$, and after this answer it seems to me like that is going to be false